# Group array of objects in array of arrays -JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping, arrayobject

I'm trying to group an array of objects in array of arrays by 'group' key in objects.

Current array:

```
array =
[
    [{name:’a’,age:’4’,group:’15’},{name:’b’,age:’4’,group:’15’}, 
     {name:’c’,age:’4’,group:’15’}],
    [{name:’aa’,age:’6’,group:’12’},{name:’bb’,age:’6’,group:’12’}],
    [{name:’d’,age:’5’,group:’15’},{name:’e’,age:’5’,group:’15’}, 
     {name:’f’,age:’5’,group:’15’}],
    [{name:’dd’,age:’7’,group:’12’}, 
     {name:’ee’,age:’7’,group:’12’{name:’ff’,age:’7’,group:’12’}]
]
```

I want to get an array looking like:

```
newArray=  [
        {15:[[{name:’a’,age:’4’,group:’15’},{name:’b’,age:’4’,group:’15’}, 
              {name:’c’,age:’4’,group:’15’}],[{name:’d’,age:’5’,group:’15’}, 
              {name:’e’,age:’5’,group:’15’},{name:’f’,age:’5’,group:’15’}]
        },
        {12:[[{name:’aa’,age:’6’,group:’12’},{name:’bb’,age:’6’,group:’12’}],
            [{name:’dd’,age:’7’,group:’12’},{name:’ee’,age:’7’,group:’12’}, 
             {name:’ff’,age:’7’,group:’12’}]]
        }
    ]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flat to flatten the arrays.
Create object maps to group by group and age.
Extract individual objects per key in object map, and unwrap ages objects to arrays.
ages are numbers, and ES2015 sorts integer indexes, so the order is already sorted by age.

Note: your JavaScript data object is invalid JavaScript due to use of non-standard single quote.  And there are unclosed brackets in your data.  Parsed as string sanitized to JSON.

```js
res = 
Object.entries(
array.flat().reduce((res,x)=>{
  const {age, group} = x
  res[group] = res[group] || {}
  res[group][age] = res[group][age] || []
  res[group][age].push(x)
  return res
},{})
).map(([k,v])=>({[k]: Object.values(v)}))

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
array =
JSON.parse(`[
    [{name:’a’,age:’4’,group:’15’},{name:’b’,age:’4’,group:’15’}, 
     {name:’c’,age:’4’,group:’15’}],
    [{name:’aa’,age:’6’,group:’12’},{name:’bb’,age:’6’,group:’12’}],
    [{name:’d’,age:’5’,group:’15’},{name:’e’,age:’5’,group:’15’}, 
     {name:’f’,age:’5’,group:’15’}],
    [{name:’dd’,age:’7’,group:’12’}, 
     {name:’ee’,age:’7’,group:’12’},{name:’ff’,age:’7’,group:’12’}]
]`.replace(/’/g,'"').replace(/(name|age|group)/g,'"$1"'))
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked ,you are amazing!!!!!!

Comment: If an answer helped you, click the checkmark next to it to [accept it as the solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
array =
[
    [{name:'a',age:'4',group:'15'},
     {name:'b',age:'9',group:'15'}, 
     {name:'c',age:'6',group:'15'},
     {name:'c',age:'8',group:'15'},
     {name:'c',age:'4',group:'15'}],
    [{name:'aa',age:'6',group:'12'}]
];
const groupByAge = (acc, elem)=>{
    acc[elem.age] = acc[elem.age]?  [...acc[elem.age],elem] : [elem];
    return acc
}
var res = array.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
var key = "";
  elem.forEach(k=> {
       key  = k.group;
       acc[k.group] = acc[k.group] ?  [...acc[k.group], k] : [k];
   });
  var temp= acc[key].reduce(groupByAge, {});
  acc[key] = Object.values(temp);
  return acc
},{});

console.log([res])
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking also to separate 'age' key

Comment: I need to group by group and age

Comment: Any Ideas how to do this?

Comment: I added input and output to question.  array= input , newArray=output

Comment: the key should be the 'group' value , and the value should be array of arrays cording to age

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to get the exact same output like in question?

Comment: @ABGR he wants an array of arrays, with each array grouping together ages, like in my answer

Comment: @user12083483 Ah, okay. Yes you can do so. Check the updted one. But this would be further adding to complexity. Anyway.